# How to get rid of the full path to the test in pytest's console output?

Tags: python, pytest

I have a folder with many tests, and when the pytest is running the output looks like it:

```
tests/t1.py F [ 14%]

tests/t2.py . [ 28%]

tests/t3.py . [ 42%]

tests/t4.py . [ 57%]

tests/t5.py . [ 71%]

tests/t6.py . [ 85%]

tests/t7.py F  [ 100%]
```

I want to get rid of "tests/" in the output of the pytest.

Is it possible?

Comment: I'm curious why you want to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0):

First, let's start with the *why* the output is like that.

That path prepended to all the tests is the relative path of all the tests pytest found during test discovery phase, **with respect to the `rootdir`** (ee the section on [Initialization: determining rootdir and configfile](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/customize.html#initialization-determining-rootdir-and-configfile)). Given that you have "`tests`" prepended to all the tests in the report, I assume you are running the tests *outside* of the `tests` directory.

Consider this `app` folder with a `tests` folder, which organizes tests into UTs and ITs:

```
app$ tree -I *.pyc -I __pycache__ .
.
└── tests
    ├── it
    │   └── test_apis.py
    └── ut
        └── test_utilA.py
```

If I run it *outside* of `tests`,

```
$ pytest tests --no-summary
=========================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.12, pytest-6.2.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /path/to/app
collected 3 items                                                                                                                                                                                                      

tests/it/test_apis.py ..
tests/ut/test_utilA.py .
```

The `rootdir` is the `app` folder and then `tests/it` and `tests/ut` gets prepended to all the nested tests pytest discovered under `tests`. The `rootdir` + `tests/**/*.py` **provides the full path to each test**. If you `cd` first into `tests` and run it from inside `app/tests`, then you should get:

```
app$ cd tests
tests$ pytest . --no-summary
========================================================================= 
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.12, pytest-6.2.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /path/to/app/tests
collected 3 items

it/test_apis.py ..
ut/test_utilA.py .
```

The `rootdir` has changed, and now only `it/` and `ut/` is prepended to complete the path to the tests.

Now, for the *how* to get rid of "tests/" in the output of the pytest.

### The GOOD Approach

The recommended approach is to run your tests inside the same folder as the tests themselves, such that your `rootdir` includes `tests/` and the report would just include the test filename itself.

```
app$ pwd
/path/to/app

app$ cd tests/ut
ut$ pytest . --no-summary
=========================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.12, pytest-6.2.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /path/to//app/tests/ut
collected 1 item 

test_utilA.py .
=========================================================================

ut$ cd ../../
app$ cd tests/it

it$ pytest . --no-summary
=========================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.12, pytest-6.2.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /path/to/app/tests/it
collected 2 items

test_apis.py ..
=========================================================================
```

Depending on how your tests are organized, it should be quite easy to write a script to go into each directory and run `pytest .` on each one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

pushd tests/ut
pytest .
popd

pushd tests/it
pytest .
popd
```

### The BAD Approach

A hacky solution could be writing a [pytest hook function](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/writing_hook_functions.html), such as the [`pytest_itemcollected`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_itemcollected) hook, that modifies the test item's [`nodeid`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html?highlight=nodeid#pytest.nodes.Node.nodeid), which is a string  denoting the "address" of the test. Add a `conftest.py` under your `tests` directory:

```
app$ tree -I *.pyc -I __pycache__ .
.
└── tests
    ├── conftest.py        # <-----------------
    ├── it
    │   └── test_apis.py
    └── ut
        └── test_utilA.py
```

```
import pytest

@pytest.hookimpl(trylast=True)
def pytest_itemcollected(item):
    old_nodeid = item._nodeid
    new_nodeid = old_nodeid.rsplit('/', maxsplit=1)[-1]
    item._nodeid = new_nodeid
    return item
```

`old_nodeid` gets a value such as `tests/it/test_apis.py::test_post`.
`new_nodeid` removes the path to just `test_apis.py::test_post`

Now you can just run it from outside the `tests` directory,

```
app$ pytest tests -v --no-summary
=========================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.12, pytest-6.2.1, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: /path/to/app
collected 3 items

test_apis.py::test_get PASSED
test_apis.py::test_post PASSED
test_utilA.py::test_util PASSED
```

...and the relative path to `rootdir` (i.e. `"tests/"`) is now removed.

This is a bad approach though, because:

1. It depends on this "private" `_nodeid` attribute (the [`nodeid`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference/reference.html?highlight=nodeid#pytest.nodes.Node.nodeid) is actually a property and is probably not meant to be modified directly/externally).
2. It might cause problems with other pytest reporting options (pytest-html, `--junit-xml`) or with other pytest plugins (ex. pytest-cov for coverage reporting).
3. It makes it harder to get the actual path to the test, especially for projects that neatly organized their tests into directories and groups. It also makes it confusing for tests with the same name. If a test fails, it adds extra work to figure out where to find the failing test.
4. It doesn't remove the path when used with more [verbose/`-vvv`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/how-to/output.html?highlight=verbose#verbosity) options.